# Showing "No batteries available" on kubuntu 18.04 in Lenovo G450 laptop

Tags: battery

I installed kubuntu 18.04 on my Lenovo G450 laptop. But in the system tray when i am hovering my mouse pointer on the battery icon it's showing that "No Batteries Available". How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, installing upower helped.

```
apt-get install upower
```

Comment: This is happening to me on Kubuntu 19.10, and `upower` is already installed